# Como faço para incluir um arquivo necessário para realização de um teste no contexto de execução do Live Unit Testing

Tags: testes-de-unidade, visual-studio-2017

Boa tarde, a todos.

Meus testes unitários dependem de um arquivo de configuração para passarem. Porém, quando os testes rodam por meio de [Live Unit Testing](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing) (LUT) eles falham por não encontrar tal arquivo.

Atualmente o LUT roda dentro de `[...]\.vs\[solução]\lut\0\t\[projeto]\Debug\netcoreapp2.0`. Não adianta jogar o arquivo nesta pasta porque ele some toda vez que o LUT roda.

Então, como faço para incluir um arquivo necessário para realização de um teste no contexto de execução do Live Unit Testing?

Comment: Cara, me lembro que nas propriedades do arquivo você seleciona o que deve acontecer com ele no processo de build. Tem uma forma que faz com que ele fique na pasta bin. Te ajuda?

Comment: Ok, funcionou! Você está falando do "Copy to output directory". Eu havia testado antes mas não devo ter dado tempo para que a cópia fosse realizada. Valeu!

Comment: Imagina... Que bom que funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

O DiegoSantos trouxe luz ao problema.
Basta alterar a propriedade "Copy to Output Directory" do arquivo para "Copy Aways".

Valeu Diego!